# Code works, but "WHERE" doesn't

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP/MySQL code that works - but the "WHERE" clauses that are commented out do not.

If I run them I get the following error msg:

```
"**Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SCW_Files\ReadAllBowls.php on line 25**"
```

Why am I getting this error?

This code reads one table of the database scw-db, finds the txtSourceWood value, then searches a second table for a matching value, then reads data for that row. The results are then formatted into a csv format, displayed on the screen as well as being saved to a csv file to be used in Excel.

If I can use the "WHERE" clause to work in the second select, do I need to use the loop code to get the txtSourceWood match, or can I just use it directly in the code?

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","****","*****");
if(! $conn )
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$sql = 'SELECT intProductID FROM tblsplintersbowlinventory';

mysql_select_db('scw-db');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

$price = "0.00";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblsplintersBowlinventory ORDER BY intProductID");// WHERE txtVenue == 'Shoreline 2017'");

$Sqfile = fopen("SCW_Sq.csv", "w");
$Sq_record = 'ProductID, ProductBowlCode, Venue, ProductBowlPriceSold, SalesTax, ProductBowlProceeds, SourceWood, WoodIDcode, Price, Tax, Shipping, Cost, Profit';
fwrite($Sqfile, $Sq_record);
fwrite($Sqfile, "\n");              

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row['curProductBowlPriceSold'] > $price) {
        $found = strpos($row['txtVenue'], '2017');
        if($found) {
            $result_wood = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oldtblsplinterswoodinventory ORDER BY oldtxtWoodIDcode");// WHERE oldtxtWoodIDcode = $row['intProductID']");
            while ($row_wood = mysql_fetch_array($result_wood))
            {
                if($row_wood['oldtxtWoodIDcode'] == $row['txtSourceWood']){
                    $Profit = $row['curProductBowlProceeds'] - $row_wood['oldcurCost'];
                    echo "{$row['intProductID']}, {$row['txtProductBowlCode']}, {$row['txtVenue']}, {$row['curProductBowlPriceSold']}, {$row['curSalesTax']}, {$row['curProductBowlProceeds']}, ";
                    echo "{$row_wood['oldtxtWoodIDcode']}, {$row_wood['oldcurPrice']}, {$row_wood['oldcurTax']}, {$row_wood['oldcurShipping']}, {$row_wood['oldcurCost']}  <br>";

                    $Sq_record = '#'.$row['intProductID'].','.$row['txtProductBowlCode'].','.$row['txtVenue'].','.$row['curProductBowlPriceSold'].','.$row['curSalesTax'].','.$row['curProductBowlProceeds'].','.$row['txtSourceWood'].','.$row_wood['oldtxtWoodIDcode'].','.$row_wood['oldcurPrice'].','.$row_wood['oldcurTax'].','.$row_wood['oldcurShipping'].','.$row_wood['oldcurCost'].','.$Profit;
                    fwrite($Sqfile, $Sq_record);
                    fwrite($Sqfile, "\n");              
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
echo "Done\n";
fclose($Sqfile);
mysql_close($conn);
?
```

Comment: Do you have any idea what happens to the above code when your `php` version is `7.0+` ?

Comment: could you show us the real code that is not working? without commenting out the failing parts

Comment: You have `==` in `WHERE` statement. Change it to single character `=`.

Comment: Please stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to put the where before order by, second the format of your query should be like bellow.

```
$result_wood = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oldtblsplinterswoodinventory WHERE oldtxtWoodIDcode = '".$row['intProductID']."' ORDER BY oldtxtWoodIDcode");// WHERE oldtxtWoodIDcode = $row['intProductID']");
```

Hop this will help you out.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! It also removed the need for the inner loop.

Comment: As to the comments on versions, I haven't needed to use this in over a year, so I probably need to check into upgrades - when I have the time.